# weird behavior of c++ vector constructor

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I noticed some weird behavior of c++ vector constructor, can anybody explain it for me? Thanks.

Code snippet 1 works:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <ostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string str = "The quick brown fox";

  stringstream strstr(str);

  istream_iterator<string> start(strstr);
  vector<string> results(start, istream_iterator<string>());

  ostream_iterator<string> oit(cout, "\n");
  copy(results.begin(), results.end(), oit);
}
```

but code snippet 2 doesn't:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <ostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string str = "The quick brown fox";

  stringstream strstr(str);

  vector<string> results(istream_iterator<string>(strstr), istream_iterator<string>());

  ostream_iterator<string> oit(cout, "\n");
  copy(results.begin(), results.end(), oit);
}
```

The only difference is the first parameter in the constructor of the vector.

Comment: How does it "not work"?

Comment: The most vexing parse strikes again.

Comment: The answers below are correct in the diagnosis, but I would simply suggest an alternative solution, which is, IMO, far more comprehensible. Declare your iterators in a seperate statement from your vector. `istream_iterator<string> b(strstr), e; vector<string> results(b,e);`

Comment: @BenjaminLindley yep, added in the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) :

```
 vector<string> results(istream_iterator<string>(strstr), istream_iterator<string>());
```

Is parsed as a function called `results` returning a `vector` and taking one parameter named `strstr` of type `istream_iterator<string>` and one unnamed parameter of type "function taking no parameter and returning `istream_iterator<string>`" .

Change it to :

```
vector<string> results = vector<string>(istream_iterator<string>(strstr), istream_iterator<string>());
```

Or you could add parenthesis, but it's not much readable either :

```
vector<string> results( ( istream_iterator<string>(strstr) ), istream_iterator<string>());
```

As suggested by BenjaminLindley in the comments, a more readable / less error-prone way is to declare your iterators in separate statements :

```
auto begin = istream_iterator<string>(strstr);
auto end = istream_iterator<string>();
vector<string> results(begin, end);
```

---

**Note:**

Some compilers, such as clang, warn on this :

> warning: parentheses were disambiguated as a function declaration [-Wvexing-parse]

Comment: I also think "most vexing parse" is the answer. However, I'm confused that I cannot even compile the second example. I always thought "most vexing parse" is like a noop?!

Comment: @PhilippClaßen : no, the declaration **is not** an error. However, using `results` as a vector is .

Comment: Ah, you are right. :-)

Comment: Wouldn't curly braces also work here?

Comment: @remyabel they would in c++11

Answer (score 0):

The compiler considers this statement

```
vector<string> results(istream_iterator<string>(strstr), istream_iterator<string>());
```

as a function declaration that has return type `vector<string>` and two parameters, the first of type `istream_iterator<string>`, and the second of type "function that has return type `istream_iterator<string>` and no parameters". Use instead either

```
vector<string> results( ( istream_iterator<string>(strstr) ), istream_iterator<string>());
```

or

```
vector<string> results( { istream_iterator<string>(strstr), istream_iterator<string>() } );
```

That it would be more clear then a declarator may be enclosed in parentheses. So you can write for example

```
int f( int (x), int (y) );
```

Or

```
int ( x ) = 10;
```